# increase opencv webcam speed

Tags: python, opencv, webcam-capture

i need to capture a video with my webcam. I would like to use open cv for my usage.
The skript you can find down under needs a bunch of time to start the capturing.
Does any of you know a solution to speed up this skript ?

I tried to decrease the webcam ratio to 640x480.

```
webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
##Video Codec
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP4V')
width = 640
height = 480



video = VideoWriter(dir_path +"\\" + folder +"\\" + Name +".mp4",fourcc, 20.0, (width,height))



while (True):
    # lese aus Webcam
    ret, frame = webcam.read()
    if ret == False:
        print("Device not Found")
        break
    # Webcam Bild anzeigen
    cv2.imshow('Webcam', frame)
    #print("Aufnahme gestartet")
    # Videosequenz in Datei ablegen
    video.write(frame)
    #Erkennen, ob die Esc-Taste gedrückt wurde
    c = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if c == 27:
        break
## Alle Fenster schließen
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
## Video Aufnahme freigeben
webcam.release()
video.release()
```

Comment: This Code needs ~20+ sec. to start the capture.

Comment: which line of code exactly takes 20+s to execute? Can you debug it?

Comment: To start the cv2.imshow() takes the most of the time. I dont know why.

Comment: how do you determine the time taken by each line of the code? is your system broken in some way? *what is* your system?

Comment: I diffed the answer below... the single change is a `webcam.read()` *in triplicate*, effectively reading three frames, throwing two of those away, and only writing the third. you decide if that's useful to you. -- the `imshow` shouldn't take much time at all. something before it must be taking up that time. that's why I asked how measured time.

Comment: @bfris no, VideoWriter will **not** rescale anything. if you give it frames that are not the exact size you promised it in the constructor, it will silently discard those. on such basics, please refrain from speculation. and do not ever recommend those magic numbers (3 and 4) to anyone. they have names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change is a webcam.read() in triplicate, effectively reading three frames, skiping first two frames, and only writing the third frame. Hope it will work

```
webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
##Video Codec
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP4V')
width = 640
height = 480



video = VideoWriter(dir_path +"\\" + folder +"\\" + Name +".mp4",fourcc, 20.0, (width,height))



while (True):
    # lese aus Webcam
    ret, frame = webcam.read()
    ret, frame = webcam.read()
    ret, frame = webcam.read()

    if ret == False:
        print("Device not Found")
        break
    # Webcam Bild anzeigen
    cv2.imshow('Webcam', frame)
    #print("Aufnahme gestartet")
    # Videosequenz in Datei ablegen
    video.write(frame)
    #Erkennen, ob die Esc-Taste gedrückt wurde
    c = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if c == 27:
        break
## Alle Fenster schließen
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
## Video Aufnahme freigeben
webcam.release()
video.release()
```

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks Buddy! Could you Explain, why it is neccessary to get the frame and ret 3 times ?